# Unable to use range operator to find the text matching from a file

Tags: perl

I am not able to use range operator In my below program to find the text between start and end of 2 texts provided i.e. $kw1 and $kw2.I am reading both $kw1 and @kw2 from a file called oiutput.txt In this program.
Can someone please help to tell why my range operator does not give the o/p I want ?

```
my $file = "output.txt";

my $kw1 = "Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)";
my $kw2 = "CSeq: 3 REGISTER";   

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
my @content = <$fh>;

#print @content;

foreach (@content) {

#print $kw1;
#print $kw2;

if (/$kw1/ .. /$kw2/) {
    print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Sample data I am search from Is :

```
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
                Temp
                Temp
                Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
        Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
CSeq: 0 REGISTER
```

Comment: Escape the `\(REGISTER\)`.

Comment: I am still getting #   Failed test 'data structures should be the same'
#   at E:\Automation Related\Perl Scripts - ALL\IMS_debugging\test.pl line 17.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{j} = '867-5309x'
#     $expected->{j} = '867-5309'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.

Comment: Could do with some sample data that you're matching against.

Comment: Also: I'm not sure range operators work quite as well inside a foreach loop. Normally I'd do it within `while ( <$fh> ) { ` ...

Comment: added sample Data. with while loop It;s no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think first and foremost - your problem is that range operator is the wrong way around, because `CSeq: 3 REGISTER` comes *before* `Session Initiation Protocol \(REGISTER\)` in the file.

But you've commented with some test results:

> 1 not ok 1 - data structures should be the same # Failed test 'data structures should be the same' # at E:\Automation Related\Perl Scripts - ALL\IMS_debugging\test.pl line 17. # Structures begin differing at: # $got->{j} = '867-5309x' # $expected->{j} = '867-5309' # Looks like you failed 1 test of 1

That doesn't in any way match the sample you've given us - the number there isn't present in the data, nor is the `x`.

But anyway, this does work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "output.txt";


my $kw1 = "Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)";
my $kw2 = "CSeq: 3 REGISTER";   

while (<DATA>) {

   if ( /\Q$kw2\E/ ... /\Q$kw1\E/ ) {
      print;
   }
}


__DATA__
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
                Temp
                Temp
                Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
        Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
CSeq: 0 REGISTER
```

You need the `\Q` `\E` because `()` is a regex meta character. You could use `quotemeta` instead.

If you needed to match the *second* instance of 'Session Initiation Protocol' then matching whitespace will do it.

```
if ( /\Q$kw2\E/ ... /\s\Q$kw1\E/ )
```

Comment: Thank you @Sobrique. Is there any other way to grab a particular text from a file apart from the range operator ?

Comment: I am asking this because the above program Is just capturing the data based on the kw1 and kw2 and If there are more than one kw1 and kw2 present In the Input file Is there any control to grab them one by one considering all occurrence have the same text for kw1 and kw2..

Comment: Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
occurrence-1
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
occurrence-2
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
temp data here
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
occurrence-3

Comment: Yes, but I'd probably tackle that entirely differently, and so I'd suggest posting that as a different question. Include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok Thanks.I have posted another topic for this named - How to extract a particular data between 2 strings from a text file In sequence or a control manner If more than one such Instances are met

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might do, have not tested, so please match.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  my $file = "output.txt";

  open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
  while ( <$fh> ) {

  if (/Session Initiation Protocol \(REGISTER\)/ .. /CSeq: 3 REGISTER/) {
      print "$_\n";
      }
  }
```

Comment: I am getting error....1..1
not ok 1 - data structures should be the same
#   Failed test 'data structures should be the same'
#   at E:\Automation Related\Perl Scripts - ALL\IMS_debugging\test.pl line 17.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{j} = '867-5309x'
#     $expected->{j} = '867-5309'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.

Comment: There's no where in this code that `x` could have come from. Your test is doing something weird. Or your input isn't _exactly_ what you said it was.

Comment: I am using the same Input I have pasted above. I think x is nothing but some garbage value.

Comment: `867-5309` also doesn't appear in the output

Comment: I think again It's some garbage value as It Is not Inside the Input.